# Outputting a query of rows to a table in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm using the below code to output rows from my table called data_cases:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mydb.data_cases 
WHERE id=123 ORDER BY log_date_time DESC';

$result = pg_query($query) or die("Failed".$query);

$line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC);

while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {     
        echo "\t\t<td>".$col_valuez."</td>\n";        
}
```

The above code works only when there are multiple records that match that ID. if there is only one matching row, I get nothing. I believe I should be handling the data rendering part differently somehow. It seems like only one record would still work as an array. I'm just confused as to why the foreach would ignore a single row. How should I write it in a way that it works for one or more rows matching properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following code added an extra time before the while loop

```
$line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC);
```

remove this line and it should work as expected

Answer (score 2):

It's "ignoring" the single row resultset because you are consuming it:

```
$line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC);
```

That line (before your `while` statement) is consuming the first line of the result set before you do anything with it.

Just remove it altogether.